# CSS Multiple Images With Same Height

Tags: css, image, height

Okay, on a new Website of mine I want to have an area for featured images like in the ["twentyfourteen wordpress theme"](http://twentyfourteendemo.wordpress.com/). So my basic structure of an element is:

```
<aside><a href="#">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://espacio-creativo.sutomaji.net/assets/spotlight/quantumenergy/full.png"/>
  <figcaption>

  <div class="cats">Blender, Can</div>
    Blender Energy</figcaption>   
  </figure>
</a></aside>
```

what I get is something like this:
[image: v1]

but I want to have something like this:
[image: v2]

and I have no idea howto solve this... a part of my css code:

```
.featured aside {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;       
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;

}

.featured aside figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    display: inline;

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Anyone who knows howto do this, prefered without any javascript?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQu6V)

Comment: Will you put all your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Does all your images have the same height?

Comment: I'm guessing that they don't.  Try changing the `height` in your `.featured aside figure img` to a fixed pixel height.

Comment: @Huangism , steinmas: yes they don't have. And when I use height, the image has a wrong ratio.

Comment: @TomSchneider well then you need to make sure the images have the same ratio, then problem solved

Comment: @TomSchneider do you care if the images are the same width?  Can one picture be wider than another?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `height` in your `.featured aside figure img` css from 100% to a fixed pixel height.

Answer (score 0):

However, if you decide to JavaScript ...

```
var height_table = $('.featured aside a figure div img').height();

$('.featured').css({'height' : height_table + 90});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nQu6V/2/